# How page redirect in mvc3 controller foe jquerymobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I developed a jquery mobile application in ASP.NET MVC3. In this I have created an application for Desktop and mobile.  When I click the login button in either application (desktop or mobile), it is working fine. But when i want a page redirect from my controller to another view page it does not work in the mobile application.  It shows an error like "Error page loding". The url is **http://localhost:1234/#/**  When I redirect to another view, I use 
  **return RedirectToAction("Index", "Settings");**.  It then shows the error.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add some code you're trying?

Comment: Yes I try to do that.